# Avoid format-extension mismatch message when opening Excel "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format?

Tags: excel, xml, export-to-excel

I'm adding an export function to my software that creates an Excel spreadsheet, and the most convenient format I can see to do that is the "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format -- this is what it is called in the "save as" types dropdown.  If you save any spreadsheet as this type, you'll see it's a nice, readable XML format that preserves formatting.

So I have added a function that exports data to this format, for opening up into excel, preferably by double clicking on the exported file in Windows.  However, if I name the file with the extension .XLS so that it opens when you double click (which will be required for this client), excel gives a warning on opening "The file format and extension of xyz don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe.  Unless you trust its source, don't open it.  Do you want to open it anyway?"  If you open it anyway, it opens perfectly with all the formatting we wanted.

Is there a way from the file creation side that we can avoid this message?  Is there an extension we can use that will provide the double-click-open-in-excel explorer action, and avoid the mismatch message?  Or can we create the file in a way so that it doesn't appear mismatched to Excel?  Thanks!

Comment: Save with .XML extension and associate the .XML extension with Excel,  that way Excel just will open the file with a double click. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs-in-windows-e5d82cad-17d1-c53b-3505-f10a32e1894d

Comment: Thank you, but curious like I said if I can do this on the file creation side, since I won't have control over the users' machines.  But again, thanks.